# Unwanted Characters in an Informatica Workflow XML

Tags: xml, unix, character-encoding

I am working on automating the check for best practices of SQL Queries present in Informatica Workflows.

I thought of using the Workflow XML, for the purpose of getting all the SQL queries in a Workflow, But when I do a `grep` or `vi` on the .XML file in UNIX, some of the characters get converted to unwanted characters.
For example:

```
' - &apos
> - &gt
< - &lt
```

I guess this might be a character encoding issue. The encoding of the XML file is ISO-8859-1. I tried converting the encoding to UTF-8 and UTF-16, but I still faced the same issue.

It would be great if somebody can help me sort out this issue.

Also, is there some other way to get the SQLs in a workflow, which could serve my purpose.

Comment: These are called "html entities" (and there is actually a semicolon after each).  It has nothing to do with XML or UTF-8; something else in the workflow introduced them.

Comment: This is not an encoding issue. This is how XML escapes special characters. Imagine if you wanted to use a `"`, then you could use `&quot;`. If you're using an application that can parse XML, then it will handle these correctly. However, I think you will struggle with `grep`. I would advise looking for XML parsing libraries.

Comment: Robert is spot on... consider that xml is a tag based language and tags are defined using < and > characters so if these characters weren't converted to their escaped forms then the resulting file would not be well formed thus unable to be read by an xml parser.

Comment: It is possible to feed in the workflow xml to a mapping as an xml source and with a little trial and error you can extract those fields which contain sql...